# Powershell - new-website cmdlet not working when called via web interface

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I hope someone can help me with the following :

I’ve created a script to install a web site based on an existing site. 
The script performs several steps - copy dirs, restore a DB, create website and application pool etc.
 It runs fine from the Powershell CLI under an Administrator account.
I created a WinForms frontend for this script that references Powershell and also executes that script just fine. 
Now I want to create a web frontend for it. (as explained here : http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html) 
However I can’t get the ‘new-website’ cmdlet to work via the web frontend. All the other steps in the script work, including ‘new-WebappPool’ (I can see the new appPool in IIS manager). I don’t get any errors..
I’ve made sure the script runs with Administrator rights (security is **not** a concern at this point) 
Below is some output from the Powershell transcript :

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200106164117
Username: NNN-WEB\adminArr     <-- Administrator account
RunAs User: NNN-WEB\adminArr
Machine: NNN-WEB (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0)
Host Application: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap DefaultAppPool -v v4.0 -l webengine4.dll -a \\.\pipe\iisipmd4bdced8-d455-428b-b9ef-8b3e2bfb38dd -h C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config -w  -m 0 -t 20 -ta 0
Process ID: 8448
PSVersion: 5.1.14393.3383
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14393.3383
BuildVersion: 10.0.14393.3383
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
```

Comment: What is the error? What's the application pool identity?

Comment: could you share which command you are trying to run?

Comment: There is no error and the applicationPool identity is set to an Admin account  and 
    
the cmdlet that fails is 'new-website' (as stated in my post)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below PowerShell command to create a site in iis:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
New-WebAppPool NewAppPool
New-Website -Name "mike" -Port 8086 -PhysicalPath c:\casp -ApplicationPool NewAppPool
```

[image]

[image]

Do not forget to refresh the iis after running the command.

Comment: Thanks for testing - this helped me fix the problem - see my answer for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, the  'New-Webbinding' cmdlet now fails because it cannot find the site just created : New-WebBinding : Cannot find path 'IIS:\Sites\qlink_jan13d' because it does not exist.

However, when I do : dir iis:\sites in the PowerShell cli, the site is listed  
Also, the new-webbinding command works fine when I do it from the CLI..

So this web interface just doesn't work right..

Comment: @AdrievanR you need to modify the application code. which is related to the .net. you could create a new thread with the issue you faced and take the help of the .net expert.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, of course I changed the code to use 'new-webbinding' instead of 'new-website'. 
The code works in Powershell cli, but not via web interface, because it can't find the site although it is visible in IIS manager - very strange

Comment: created a new thread for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749805/powershell-new-webbinding-cmdlet-not-working-when-called-via-web-interface

Answer (score 0):

Although  in my script I also used the commands mentioned in Jalpa's example, I tried his example script anyway. I got the error 'Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'site' with unique key attributes 'name, id' respectively set to 'mike3, 2' - which I didn't get using my own script...
Thanks to this error, I figured out that if there are already some existing sites, you also have to specify the 'ID' parameter of the new-website command - so like 'new-website -Name "testsite" -Id 4 etc.'. The ID has to be a number not in use by any other sites.
This made it work :-)